# Date not showing in emails sent from form on website

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email, date

I have a form on my website that works perfectly, but I found that the date doesn't show in the e-mails I receive from the form. When checking my MailHandler.php I found there's no section for Date in the $headers, so I added one, but I obviously made something wrong since the date still doesn't show. Please, would anyone help me with how this should be written to be correct?

Thank you in advance!

```
<?php
$owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Datum:' . $_POST["date"] . "\r\n";
$subject = 'From your website  -   ' . $_POST["name"];
$messageBody = "";

if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Name: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}else{
    $headers = '';
}
if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Address: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}   
if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){      
    $messageBody .= '<p>Date: ' . $_POST['date'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){      
    $messageBody .= '<p>Fax: ' . $_POST['no'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}

try{
    if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
        throw new Exception('mail failed');
    }else{
        echo 'mail sent';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
?>
```

This is the MailHandler.ashx:

```
<?php
$owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Date:' . $_POST["date"] . "\r\n";
$subject = 'Via Marietorps hemsida  -   ' . $_POST["name"];
$messageBody = "";

if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Namn: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}else{
    $headers = '';
}
if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Leveransadress: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Telefonnummer: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}   
if($_POST['date']!='nope'){     
    $messageBody .= '<p>Datum: ' . $_POST['date'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Bestallning: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}

try{
    if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
        throw new Exception('mail failed');
    }else{
        echo 'mail sent';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

?>

This is the form.js:

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    forms:function(opt){
        if(opt===undefined)
            opt={}
        this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this),
                data=th.data('forms'),
                _={
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'4000',
                    mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php',
                    ownerEmail:'info@mydomain.se',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,
                    rx:{
                        ".name":{rx:/^[a-öA-Ö'][a-öA-Ö-' ]+[a-öA-Ö']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".state":{rx:/.\+?[0-9a-öA-Ö'][0-9a-öA-Ö-' ]+[0-9a-öA-Ö']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal)
                                        ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isRequired:function(el){                            
                        return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){                           
                        var ret=true
                        $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                            if(el.is(k))
                                ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                        })
                        return ret                          
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    },
                    validateFu:function(el){                            
                        el.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                                ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                                ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                                ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                            if(empty&&req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if(!empty)
                                if(valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                        })
                    },
                    getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                            ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                        return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                    }
                    ,submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
                                    name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                    phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                    fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                    state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                    message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })          
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=this
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            if(!data)
                (typeof opt=='object'?$.extend(_,opt):_).init.call(th),
                th.data({cScroll:_}),
                data=_
            else
                _=typeof opt=='object'?$.extend(data,opt):data
        })
        return this
    }
})
```

})(jQuery)

Comment: What does your form look like? Chances are, the problem's in there (also).

Comment: This is the first section: (function($){
 $.fn.extend({
  forms:function(opt){
   if(opt===undefined)
    opt={}
   this.each(function(){
    var th=$(this),
     data=th.data('forms'),
     _={
      errorCl:'error',
      emptyCl:'empty',
      invalidCl:'invalid',
      notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
      successCl:'success',
      successShow:'4000',
      mailHandlerURL:'bin/MailHandler.php',
      ownerEmail:'info@mixx.se',
      stripHTML:true,
      smtpMailServer:'localhost',
      targets:'input,textarea',
      controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
      validate:true,

Comment: I can't read that. Place it in your question.

Comment: That's not your "form", that's your JS. Your form should contain a named element called `date` since you're using `$_POST['date']` if you don't have one, then that's part of the problem.

Comment: Yet from what I saw in your `rx:{ ".name":...}` you don't have a mention for `date` in there.

Comment: The header needs to be `Date: ` not `Datum: `...

Comment: I have the forms.js file, the MailHandler.php and the MailHandler.ashx, then I have a script on my html-page: <script>
$(function(){
 $('#contact-form').forms({ownerEmail:'info@mydomain.se'});
});
</script>
I think that's all I have?

Comment: The `HTML` form itself where you (may/should) have `Name:________ Email:________` etc. those have (named) inputs like `<input type="text" name="name">` etc. You should have a named element for your `date`

Comment: Why do I have to have date in my rx, isn't that a part of the body message? The problem is the date not showing in the mail header only, the person who fills in the form on the website doesn't have to fill in the date.

Comment: @Shai That's just "text" `$messageBody .= '<p>Datum: ' . $_POST['date'] . '</p>' . "\n";` *"The header needs to be Date: not Datum:"*

Comment: Well if the user doesn't have to fill the date, then it won't be showing then. What is the problem then? I'm confused. If your `date` input isn't `named` then it won't show whether the user entered one or not.

Comment: I.e.: `Enter the Date: <input type="text" name="date">` However I don't know what your form itself looks like, so it's hard for me to tell how you're giving them the option.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Really? I'm talking about the `$headers .= 'Datum:' . $_POST["date"] . "\r\n";` not `$messageBody .= '<p>Datum: ' . $_POST['date'] . '</p>' . "\n";`, which is then passed as the mail headers (the 4th argument to `mail()`)...

Comment: @Shai Ok, I see what you mean now, and you're right. That shouldn't be part of the headers.

Comment: @Inger do you mean the date doesn't come from the user at all? Do you just want to use the current date/time of right now, or some other date? `$_POST['date']` is for getting a variable coming from the client... Please clarify WHAT date this is – is it meant to be something the user types into a box, or something else...

Comment: I tried to post a picture showing the problem but it said something about needing 10 reputations first so it wasn't possible.... So: When one opens ones mailbox, a list of all emails appear. The inbox-list normally shows the Subject, Sender and Date. In my inbox-list the date appears like a "?" when sent from the form, ordinary emails show a normal date. When clicking on a mail in the inbox to open it, the header shows Sender, Subject and Date. From the form the date appears like "INVALID", ordinary mails show the date normally.

Comment: If a date is not being supplied by the user and you're wanting to use the time/date the form was sent, then use `$date_form = date('h:i:s Y-m-d');` then place `$date_form` where you want it to appear in the `body` and not headers. Don't place `$headers .= 'Datum:' . $_POST["date"] . "\r\n"; not $messageBody .= '<p>Datum: ' . $_POST['date'] . '</p>' . "\n";` in your `$headers` that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: Just remove the line `$headers .= 'Datum:' . $_POST["date"] . "\r\n";`

Comment: Ok, so how you making out now, is it working? @Inger

Comment: I made like this: <?php
 $owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From:' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
 $date_form = date('h:i:s Y-m-d');
 $subject = 'Via Marietorps hemsida  -   ' . $_POST["name"];
 $messageBody = "";
but still there's no date... what don't I understand? :-)

Comment: Show me your `HTML` **form** I don't know where/how you're (originally) trying/expecting to get the date from. Plus my example about `$date_form = date('h:i:s Y-m-d');`, you need to place the `$date_form` variable INSIDE the `$messageBody` somehow as to where you want it to be shown. That's where it will/should appear. Leave `$date_form = date('h:i:s Y-m-d');` where you have it now. It's just the variable (`$date_form`) that needs to be inserted in the body.

Comment: I have this on the html-page: <script>
$(function(){
 $('#contact-form').forms({ownerEmail:'info@mydomain.se'});
});
</script>   Is it within here your string should be added as well?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you any longer. I tried my best. What I meant by your form, is not `JS`, it's the `<html><head></head><body>` part. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 2):

Your first:

`if($_POST['fax']!='nope')`

should probably be

`if($_POST['date']!='nope')`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use post to send the date, just assign the date with php date() function and print that to the headers

The php date function is reliant on timezone, so you need to set your timezone then call it.  [You can find timezones here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).  It accepts two parameters, the first is format, and the second is a time, which if left out defaults to the current time.  The 'r' in the function below sets the format of the time to 'RFC 2822 formatted date'. Check out the PHP manual for date() [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
    $yourTimezone = new DateTimeZone('your_timezone');
    $date = date('r'),
```

Then in your header array

```
   $headers .= 'Date:' . $date . "\r\n";
```